# the cursor doesn't print any data - two parameters procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have one task to solve.

Create a procedure based on which all employees who have already been employed once (job_history table) in the defined period (any variables) will be listed. The report will state: employee_id, first_name, last_name, start_date, end_date.

Treat the case if there is no employee who was employed in the given period.

Call the procedure for the years 1997 to 2007.

Procedure is compiled, and when I call it the answer is: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. But no data from my database.

My code is here:

```
create or replace procedure zamestnanci
  (s_date in job_history.start_date%type, e_date in job_history.end_date%type)
is 
begin
  for cur_r in 
    (select employees.employee_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name 
     from employees join job_history on employees.employee_id = job_history.employee_id
     where start_date = s_date and end_date = e_date
    )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.employee_id ||', '|| cur_r.first_name ||', '|| cur_r.last_name ||', '||
     s_date ||', '|| e_date );
  end loop;
  exception when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('error');
end zamestnanci;

exec zamestnanci('01.01.97', '31.12.07');
```

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Enable DMBS output in your IDE and you should be able to see the put_line statements in editor window after running the procedure.

Comment: Does dbms_output work at all, e.g. `dbms_output.put_line('Hello')`? Or is it just this  procedure? Can you trace it in the debugger and see if it enters the loop?

Comment: By the way, `exception when no_data_found then dbms_output.put_line('error');` won't be called because there's no `select into` or collection lookup, and if there was, that's really not the best way to handle it.

Comment: Are `start_date` and `end_date` dates?  Or strings?  You're passing in strings but the names imply that they ought to be dates.  Are there actually employees that started on 1997-01-01 and that left on 2007-12-31?  It seems unlikely that they are.  The question asks for anyone that was employed at some point during the provided interval-- think about the potential ways that can happen.  One way would be that the start_date was before 1997-01-01 and the end_date was after 1997-01-01 (or missing depending on how your data model works).  There are other conditions to account for as well.

Comment: @WiliamRobertson - Thank you. Yes dbms_output works at all, its just this procedure. I dont know how can I trace it in the debugger.

Comment: @Justin - start date and end date are parameters for period where employee was hired, i need to compare hire date with them

Comment: @Kristina what is the column definition for `job_history.start_date` and `job_history.end_date`? Often questions on SO say it's a date but then it turns out to be a string that looks like a date, i.e. not a date at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fetches the employees who started job at '01.01.97' and quit at '31.12.07'

try code below. also be aware date format

```
create or replace procedure zamestnanci
  (s_date in job_history.start_date%type, e_date in job_history.end_date%type)
is 
begin
  for cur_r in 
    (select employees.employee_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name 
     from employees join job_history on employees.employee_id = job_history.employee_id
     where start_date between s_date and e_date
     or end_date between s_date and e_date
     or s_date between start_date and end_date
     or e_date between start_date and end_date
    )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.employee_id ||', '|| cur_r.first_name ||', '|| cur_r.last_name ||', '||
     s_date ||', '|| e_date );
  end loop;
  exception when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('error');
end zamestnanci;

exec zamestnanci(to_date('01.01.1997', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2007', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```